# How to avoid Remove-Item PowerShell errors "process cannot access the file"?

Tags: powershell, deployment

We are using [TfsDeployer](https://web.archive.org/web/20210630222450/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=tfsdeployer) and PowerShell script to remove the folders using `Remove-Item`
before deployment of a new version.
Sometimes the PS script fails with the error:

> Remove-Item : Cannot remove item Services\bin: The process cannot
> access the file Services\bin' because it is being used by another proc
> Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination  -Recurse | Remove-Item
> <<<<  -force -recurse + CategoryInfo          :
> WriteError: (C:\Program File..\Services\bin:DirectoryInfo)
> [Remove-Item], IOException  FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

I’ve tried to follow the [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/199921/powershell-remove-force/199994#199994) (from: [Force-remove files and directories in PowerShell fails sometimes, but not always](https://serverfault.com/questions/199921/powershell-remove-force)) to pipe `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` into `Remove-Item`.

```
Get-ChildItem * -Include *.csv -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

But the error still happens periodically. We are using [unlocker](http://unlocker.en.softonic.com/) to manually kill the locking application, (it’s usually w3wp), but I prefer to find automated solution.

Another (not ideal) option is [to-suppress-powershell-errors](http://arcware.net/how-to-suppress-powershell-errors/)

```
 Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: does unlocker tell you what its doing as in is the problem the same everytime it executes?

Comment: Unlocked shows that the folder is locked by some application - usually w3wp and allow me to kill the app.

Answer (score 3):

Late, but someone might find this useful.

In an automation script, I recurse through processes to find any that is using the path of the directory I want to delete, and kill them.

Sometimes other apps might be locking a file, so I used process explorer to find handle/dll. If is ok to kill the app, I add the kill to the script.

Then remove the dir.

```
        get-process | foreach{
          $pName = $_
          if ( $pName.Path -like ( $INSTALL_PATH + '*') ) {
            Stop-Process $pName.id -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
          }
        }
       Remove-Item  -Force -Recurse $INSTALL_PATH
```

Comment: The approach you describe sounds very interesting to me, 'cause that's exactly the kind of functionality I've been dreaming to use for this problem. Still, are you sure there are no side effects? And again, after `Stop-Process`, aren't you worried that you should restart them?

Comment: @jessarah I want to `rm` a `file`, not a `dir`, so I set `$install_path = file1.xls`. It closed nearly all my apps in `windows 10` but the file was not removed. However, I could then remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You could inspect the errors given by the `Remove-Item` cmdlet.  Use the `ErrorVariable` parameter on `Remove-Item` to store its errors in a variable, then loop through it, only displaying the errors you want, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem * -Include *.csv -recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $removeErrors = @()
    $_ | Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable removeErrors
    $removeErrors | where-object { $_.Exception.Message -notlike '*it is being used by another process*' }
}
```

Comment: You should add `-force`.

Comment: This is simpler, no `foreach`: `Get-ChildItem $ziel -recurse | Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable removeErrors -Force;$removeErrors | where-object { $_.Exception.Message -notlike '*it is being used by another process*' }`

Answer (score 0):

Well as it's a web application that's locking the file, why don't you do an `iisreset /stop` before removing the item, and then `iisreset /start` afterwards?

Comment: Unfortunately, we have many sites on the server, so stop IIS is not an option, but I will check, how to  stop/start single pool.